# Using Merge with an R By class object

Tags: r, list, loops, merge

So I have a "by" class object (which is essentially a list).

It is indexed by 2 factors [id1,id2], with a list associated with each unique pair.

e.g.

```
id1:1
id2:1
1,2,3
------
id1:1
id2:2
4,4,NA
------
id1:2
id2:1
NA
```

I would like to convert this to a data frame which has 3 columns {id1,id2,value} and would take the above and return

```
id1, id2, value
1    1    1
1    1    2 
1    1    3
1    2    4
1    2    4
1    2    NA
2    1    NA
```

This can be done with a for loop but is obviously slow. I am looking to try and merge the value column back to a data frame which has indices 1 and 2.

Answer (score 1):

Answer: Use the data.table package. It is ridiculously quick for these sorts of problems.